# TensorFlow 2.4: loss: 0.0000e+00 but accuracy: 0.2682 only, does that make sense?

Tags: tensorflow, loss-function

I am strugling to understand how the loss (sparse_categorical_crossentropy) can be zero, but the accuracy << 1? Also the "trained" model does not provide good results. How can it be that the loss gives a zero, despite the model not being well trained:

```
Epoch 1/3
182/182 [==============================] - 496s 3s/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.2682 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.2729
Epoch 2/3
147/182 [=======================>......] - ETA: 1:29 - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.2645
```

The model:

```
    number_of_categories = len(class_names)
    loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'    
    metrics = ['accuracy']
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(30, (5, 5), activation=activation, input_shape=(pheight, pwidth, 3)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((5, 5)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(40, (5, 5), activation=activation))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((5, 5)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(50, (5, 5), activation=activation))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((5, 5)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=activation))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(number_of_categories, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=metrics)
```

Any thoughts of what is going wrong here are highly welcome ...

And this is the model fit:

```
    history = model.fit(x=training_generator,
                        validation_data=test_generator,
                        batch_size=batch_size,
                        use_multiprocessing=False,
                        workers=1,
                        epochs=epochs,
                        steps_per_epoch=len(training_generator),
                        max_queue_size=1)
```

Comment: please show code for model.fit

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: I had accidentally used small float number likes 0.01 instead 1 as ground truth values (y_true). This did cause the wrong behaviour. By scalling it up and rounding to 1 instead it now works.